# Customizing a serializer of Djoser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, djoser

I created two customized serializers for the user_create and current_user endpoints in Djoser.
I also wanted to have re_password field in user register. But when I add `"USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True` in the settings of Djoser, my serializer for create user doesn't work and default serializer works. Could you tell me where is the problem?

here is my serializer:

```
from djoser.serializers import UserSerializer as BaseUserSerializer, UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserCreateSerializer

class UserCreateSerializer(BaseUserCreateSerializer):    
    class Meta(BaseUserCreateSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']


class UserSerializer(BaseUserSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password']
```

and here is settings of Djoser:

```
DJOSER = {
    "USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True,
    "SERIALIZERS": {
        'user_create': 'core.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'core.serializers.UserSerializer',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I inherited from UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer instead of UserCreateSerializer to have both re_password field and my customized serializer.
And also I deleted `"USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True` from settings and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove `"USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE": True` from settings.py. You simply need to define new serializer

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer

class CustomUserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer(UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer):    
    class Meta(UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

and in settings.py

```
DJOSER = {
    "SERIALIZERS": {
        'user_create_password_retype': 'core.serializers.CustomUserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer',
    }
}
```

as it uses `user_create_password_retype` serializer when `"USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE"` is set to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 from djoser.serializers import UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer
    class CustomUserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer(UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer):
        class Meta(UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer.Meta):
            fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password']


DJOSER = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '#/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '#/username/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': '#/activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,

    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,

    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'core.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'core.serializers.UserSerializer',
        'user_create_password_retype': 'core.serializers.CustomUserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer',
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

This is worked for me:

Settings Djoser:

```
"SERIALIZERS":{
    'user_create':'account.serializers.CustomUserCreateSerializer',
    'user':'account.serializers.CustomUserCreateSerializer',
    'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    'user_create_password_retype': 'account.serializers.CustomUserCreateSerializer',
    'password_reset': 'account.serializers.PasswordResetEmailSentSerializer',
},
```

Custom Serializer:

```
from djoser.serializers import SendEmailResetSerializer, UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer
from rest_framework import serializers
from account.models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreateSerializer(UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer):
    class Meta(UserCreatePasswordRetypeSerializer.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields =('id','first_name','last_name','email','phone_number','password',)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).